# Will SPFileCollection.Add method threw exception if upload fail in C#?

Tags: development

In my project, it has a method which to upload file to SharePoint Library, then return bool if upload success.

So, how can i check the success of the uploading?

Code:

```
{ 
    //many codes
    byte[] imageData = imageToByteArray(myimage);
    item.Delete();
    web.Files.Add(Path.Combine(site, fileURL), imageData );
    // if fail, isSuccess = false;
}
return isSuccess;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint if it fails to upload the file then it will raise the exception.

So what you can do is surround your code with `Try..Catch` block.

So replace your following line

```
web.Files.Add(Path.Combine(site, fileURL), imageData );
```

with this one

```
try
{
web.Files.Add(Path.Combine(site, fileURL), imageData );
isSuccess=true;
}
catch(Exception Ex)
{
isSuccess=false;
}
```

Now this will track whether there was any error during uploading the file. If file is uploaded successfully then it will return **`true`** or else it will return **`false`**.

Here I assume the variable `isSuccess` is declared globally with default value **`false`**